# Exception while parsing JSON using org.simple

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I am creating a JSON file and saving it a location. When the files are creating for the first time, there are no issues. But if the file exists and it should update the existing JSON file in the same location i am getting the following exception:
**Exception:**

```
Unexpected character (-) at position 138.
at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at nbclearn.edgate.executorService.ExecService$1.run(ExecService.java:116)
at 
Unexpected character (d) at position 123.
at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at nbclearn.edgate.executorService.ExecService$1.run(ExecService.java:116)
at 

Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at nbclearn.edgate.executorService.ExecService$1.run(ExecService.java:116)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**File Writting:**

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                                        new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/Users/smo/Desktop/Ed/"+id+".json"),
                                                "utf-8"));
                                try {
                                    writer.write(jsonDATA);
                                    }

                                    System.out.println("Done");
                                } finally {
                                    writer.close();
                                }
```

I am using org.simple libraru to see if the json file exists in the location , else it should create new file. If it exists it should update it.

**Code for Checking the JSON File:**

```
Path p = Paths.get("/Users/smo/Desktop/Ed/"+id + ".json");
                                boolean exists = Files.exists(p);
                                if(exists){
                                Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                                        "/Users/smo/Desktop/Ed/"+id + ".json"));
                                org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) obj;
```

**JSON Data:**

```
{“id1-position-backstik”: [“4289998”, "422212998", "49998", “638737”],”sum”:2a7c0d20-baf1-4c37-8ac5-eb14198eed06,”position”:1 }


                                }
```

Can anyone please suggest.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And what is it that you don't understand? The exception is telling you what's wrong. Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: it says unexpected character. But i have tested my JSONFormat using jsonlint.com where it says if its a valid JSON or not. @Tavo Can you please suggest whats going wrong here?

Comment: @Tavo i have edited the question and posted the JSON as well. Can you please suggest?

Comment: Have you tried replacing ´“´ with `"` ?. Also, [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com) says it is not a valid json. And the `sum` value, `2a7c0d20-baf1-4c37-8ac5-eb14198eed06`, should be quoted.